# Trigger AWS CodePipeline to rebuild my app via webhook

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

How would I make a webhook (which I'll be using from my CMS) to invoke my CodePipeline?

I've got a simple CodePipeline setup that looks like this.

`Source (Github) -> AWS CodeBuild -> AWS S3`

It's a Node app that builds an application based on resources from a CMS.

At the moment only committing to the Github Repository invokes CodePipeline to remake my app.

However, I'm wanting a webhook or URL trigger to invoke the CodePipeline to recreate my app when certain changes in the CMS occur.

How do I create a webhook to invoke CodePipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the cleanest way.  If you created an API Gateway that invokes a Lambda.  In the lambda you could use one of the AWS sdks to run a script.  For example, If you used Python, it would be the [boto3.start_build()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/codebuild.html#CodeBuild.Client.start_build)

That is just the first though I had.

Outside of a sdk or cli, I think Pipelines only work with ECR, S3, CodeCommit, BitBucket, and Github.